# slicing a vector shows error our of range

Tags: r, jags, rjags, r2jags

I have this part of my jags code. I really can't see where the code gets out of the range. Can anyone please see any error that I can't recognize? These are the data sizes.

```
N = 96

L = c(4,4,4,4,4)

length(media1) = 96

length(weights1) = 4

      for(t in 1:N){
        current_window_x <- ifelse(t <= L[1], media1[1:t], media1[(t - L[1] + 1):t])
        t_in_window <- length(current_window_x)
        new_media1[t] <- ifelse(t <= L[1], inprod(current_window_x, weights1[1:t_in_window]), 
        inprod(current_window_x, weights1))
      }
```

The error is (where line 41 correspond to the first line in the loop)

```
      Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
      RUNTIME ERROR:
      Compilation error on line 41.
      Index out of range taking subset of  media1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just happened on to the answer here earlier today for something I was working on.  The answer is in [this post](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/8ff806a8/).  The gist is that `ifelse()` in jags is not a control flow statement, it is a function and both the `TRUE` and `FALSE` conditions are evaluated.  So, even though you are saying to use `media1[1:t]` if `t<=L[1]`, the `FALSE` condition is also being evaluated which produces the error.

The other problem once you're able to fix that is that you're re-defining the parameter `current_window_x`, which will throw an error.  I think the easiest way to deal with the variable window width is just to hard code the first few observations of `new_media` and then calculate the remaining ones in the loop, like this:

```
new_media[1] <- media1[1]*weights1[1]
new_media[2] <- inprod(media1[1:2], weights1[1:2])
new_media[3] <- inprod(media1[1:3], weights1[1:3])
for(t in 4:N){
  new_media[t] <- inprod(media1[(t - L[1] + 1):t], weights1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @DaveArmstrong. That what I did exactly. Just hardcoded the first elements.